# Pictures do not show in Safari on iphones

Tags: html, css, mobile, safari

I recently published a website http://marishomeimprovements.com/
There is a picture in the background on the top of the page and for whatever reason, it won't load through Safari on iPhones.

html:

```
<section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="title">
            <p>The Best Remodeling Company</p>
            <h1>We Are Maris Home Improvements</h1>
            <p>Specializing in Decks, Windows, Siding and More.</p>
            <div class="giftCardAd">
                <h1 class="heading"><span id="callNow">Call Now!</span></h1>
                <h3>$25 gift card with free estimate.</h3>
                <h2>636-778-4343</h2>
                <h4>We are here for you.</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>     
</section>
```

css:

```
.home{
height: 600px;
background-image: url('../images/background.png');
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center center;
overflow: hidden;
}

.home .overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: 600px;
    padding: 70px 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.home .overlay .title h1{
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
}

.home .overlay .title p{
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.home .overlay .title .a-btn{
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #0060e2;
    color: #fff;
}

.home .overlay .title .a-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #0060e2;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .home .overlay .title .bannerImage{
        display:none;
    }

    .box .item .location{
        display:none;
    }
    .heading{
       font-size:30px; 
    }
}
```

And then some more:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .home div .title{
        margin-top:4em;
        clear:both;
        width:90%;
    }

    .home div .title h1{
        font-size:35px !important;
    }

    .giftCardAd{
        width:95%;
    }

    #live-chat{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

The issue that I have with this is that it doesn't load the picture in or at least it doesn't display it properly to the user on iPhones.
I've tried changing the format of the picture from jpg to png but nothing seems to be working.
I would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `background-attachment: fixed` it's causing the problem

[image: iPhone X Safari]